Unable to Receive Bluetooth Notifications in React Native with react-native-ble-manager
  const connectToDevice = async (deviceId:any) => {
    
    try {
      // Connect to the device
      await BleManager.connect(deviceId);
      console.log(`Connected to device: ${deviceId}`);

      // Retrieve services and characteristics
      const peripheralInfo = await BleManager.retrieveServices(deviceId);
      
      setCurrentDevice(peripheralInfo);
      const serviceUUID = "6E400001-B5A3-F393-E0A9-E50E24DCCA9E";
      const characteristicUUID = "6E400003-B5A3-F393-E0A9-E50E24DCCA9E";


    BleManager.startNotification(deviceId, serviceUUID, characteristicUUID)
    .then(() => {
      console.log("Notification started for characteristic");
    })
    .catch(error => {
      console.error("Notification start error:", error);
    });
  
    bleManagerEmitter.addListener(
        'BleManagerDidUpdateValueForCharacteristic',
        ({ value, peripheral, characteristic, service }) => {
          // Convert bytes array to string
          
          console.log(`Received ${value} for characteristic ${characteristic}`);
        }
        
      );

      
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Connection error:', error);
    }
  };


I am developing a React Native application using the react-native-ble-manager library to communicate with a Bluetooth Low Energy (BLE) device. While I can connect to the device successfully, I am having trouble receiving notifications from a specific characteristic. I have verified that the characteristic UUID is correct, but I am not receiving any data in the notification listener.
I have set up notifications for a BLE characteristic with the following UUID: 6E400003-B5A3-F393-E0A9-E50E24DCCA9E. Although the notification is successfully started (as confirmed by console logs), I do not receive any data when the device sends it.

Did you try to use an app like lightblue to check if the device is working?

yes the device is working
